# How can I install MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-5.7, ubuntu-22.04

The company I am working uses an older stack, and I need to install MySQL 5.7 on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to work on some projects locally. Does anyone knows how to do this? I just can't find anything besides installing it on Ubuntu 20.04 or lower.

Comment: Your time solving this issue may be better spent updating the code code to enable MySQL 8 going forward.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 will reach end of life in 14 months and there won't be any security patches anymore after that. Maybe you should use this upgrade effort to install MySQL 8.x instead.

Comment: Suggestion: use a Docker container

Comment: I may actually use a docker container, just need to find the right way to do this.

Comment: @JordanOliveira, it's well documented at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/. After Docker is up and running, have a look at https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql, especially at the section 'Where to Store Data'.

Answer (score 12):

download:

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb
```

select this options:

> Bionic -> MySQL Server and Cluster -> mysql-5.7 -> ok

add key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 467B942D3A79BD29
apt-get update
```

check available mysql versions:

```
apt-cache policy mysql-server


mysql-server:
      Installed: (none)
      Candidate: 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
      Version table:
         8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 500
            500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
            500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
         8.0.19-0ubuntu5 500
            500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
         5.7.37-1ubuntu18.04 500
            500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-5.7 amd64 Packages
```

and install it:

```
apt install -f mysql-client=5.7* mysql-community-server=5.7* mysql-server=5.7*
```

Done

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue for me with a small trick.What we actually need to do is edit our /etc/apt/sources.list with the source.list available in Ubuntu 20.4. eg. you will get an entry in ubuntu 22 "deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted"

so just replace jammy by bionic in all places in /etc/apt/sources.list then save and try apt update after then just simply try to install myslq sudo apt install -fmysql-server=5.7* can use this command and now you can able to install mysql successfully.

Once you are installed and mysql is up and running just make sure to revert the /etc/apt/sources.list file.

Reason for doing this is in Ubuntu 22.04 it is not bale to install all required dependencies for mysql5.7 so by editing source.list we allow to install all req dependencies.

Note: Don't use upgrade in while doing this all and make sure you revert the source.list file after myslq installed and plz mark mysql on hold for upgrade because whenever you run an upgrade command it will upgrade the mysql version to 8 from 5.

Hope this work for you. Thanks

Comment: This works for me too, but I also had to add 2 public keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 and 467B942D3A79BD29 (via apt-key command) for apt update to finish successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the key(PGP PUBLIC KEY) here to your clipboard.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/checking-gpg-signature.html

Save it in a file on your machine i.e. signature. key and then

```
sudo apt-key add signature.key
```

add the apt repo

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic mysql-5.7" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list'
```

update apt

```
sudo apt-get update
```

now check your available versions make sure there is 5.7* version at the bottom:

```
sudo apt-cache policy mysql-server
```

Now install mysql 5.7

```
sudo apt install -f mysql-client=5.7* mysql-community-server=5.7* mysql-server=5.7*
```